# call-by-value-result?

Tags: c

Is there anything like 'call-by-value result' in c programming?
If it exists , what is the difference between 'call-by-value' and 'call-by-value-result'?
Or both are same?

Comment: where did you hear this term? can you give the original context? what do you think it means?

Comment: I guess he's referring to [call-by-copy-restore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy).  First time hearing that phrase.

Comment: I am solving a mcq book on c programming.(GATE 2011 by Genius publication ISBN 978-93-80311-31-9)  There is a question:
The default parameter passing mechanism is 
(a) call by refernce
(b) call by value
(c) call by value result

and at the answer hints, they mark the option (c) (call by value result) as the right answer. which is incorrect I suppose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **call-by-value-result definition**
>
> An argument passing convention where
>   the actual argument is a variable V
>   whose value is copied to a local
>   variable L inside the called function
>   or procedure. If the procedure
>   modifies L, these changes will not
>   affect V, which may also be in scope
>   inside the procedure, until the
>   procedure returns when the final value
>   of L is copied to V. Under
>   call-by-reference changes to L would
>   affect V immediately. Used, for
>   example, by BBC BASIC V on the Acorn
>   Archimedes.

Source: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/call-by-value-result

As Oli said, C incorporates call-by-value behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Not really.  C is effectively call-by-value.  If you want different behaviour, you'll have to emulate it manually.